# How does Europa Universalis 4 handle the time speed in multiplayer?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I played only the demo of EU4, and I'm wondering how the real time aspect works in the full game, in a multiplayer game.

Is it a fixed speed, set on the beginning?
Or is it adapting to what players want on the fly (for example going at the lowest speed requested, like Imperium Galactica 2)?

Comment: I've wondered about this too. The "pausable real time" and multiplayer are both such touted features, but nobody talks about how they could possibly work together.

Comment: I played this once a few years back with a group of about 8 people. I think the host decided on the speed of the game and could change it upon request (there's VCR style buttons on the hosts screen). However, it has been so long I don't trust that as a full answer.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero - EU4 is the new one, freshly released this year

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ok, I've bought the game finally, so I can answer the question myself.*

From what I observed, time speed can be changed by the host, but also the players. It then changes it for everyone (note that I tried this only with 2 human players).

Anyone can pause the game. Other players can't unpause the game for the next 30 seconds.